# What statement do I use in main block to run this code in ubuntu terminal?

Tags: haskell

This is my code for space-age problem in exercism. After writing this code in ubuntu terminal, I was facing difficulty in running the code due to some error in main block. Help me run this code.

```
module SpaceAge (Planet(..), ageOn) where

data Planet = Mercury
            | Venus
            | Earth
            | Mars
            | Jupiter
            | Saturn
            | Uranus
            | Neptune

earthAge :: Float
earthAge = 31557600.0

ageOn' :: Float -> Float -> Float
ageOn' seconds orbital_period = seconds / (orbital_period * earthAge)

ageOn :: Planet -> Float -> Float
ageOn Mercury seconds = ageOn' seconds 0.2408467
ageOn Venus seconds = ageOn' seconds 0.61519726
ageOn Earth seconds = ageOn' seconds 1.0
ageOn Mars seconds = ageOn' seconds 1.8808158
ageOn Jupiter seconds = ageOn' seconds 11.862615
ageOn Saturn seconds = ageOn' seconds 29.447498
ageOn Uranus seconds = ageOn' seconds 84.016846
ageOn Neptune seconds = ageOn' seconds 164.79132


main = do print $ ageOn $ 100000.00
```

Comment: "Some error"? Please include that error in future questions.

Comment: If you flip the order of arguments of `ageOn'` you can remove 16 `seconds` identifiers from `ageOn` :) but it's probably best to define a function called `orbitalPeriod :: Planet -> Float` so `ageOn planet seconds = seconds / (orbitalPeriod planet * earthAge)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ageOn` takes two arguments, so you need something like this:

```
main :: IO ()
main = print $ ageOn Jupiter 100000.00
```

No need for `do` if you only have one statement.